# android app crash after adding actionbar.setsubtitle

Tags: java, android, exception

I tried to run my app (from bignerdranch) and could not run it after adding the following code:

`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            actionBar.setSubtitle("Bodies of Water");
        }`

I get a runtime exception . If i remove these lines the app runs ok . 
ofcourse i added the line @TargetApi(11)

i tried changing my target sdk, i tried copying other people's code. nothing works!!

this is my code :

```
private void updateQuestion() {

    int question = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].getQuestion();
    mQuestionTextView.setText(question);
}

private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue) {
    boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();
    int messageResId = 0;

    if (mIsCheater[mCurrentIndex]) {
        messageResId = R.string.judgment_toast;
    } else {
        if (userPressedTrue == answerIsTrue) {
            messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
        } else {
            messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (data == null) {
        return;
    }
    mIsCheater[mCurrentIndex] = data.getBooleanExtra(
            CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_SHOWN, false);
}

@TargetApi(11)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate(Bundle) called");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setSubtitle("Bodies of Water");
    }
    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(true);

        }
    });

    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false);

        }
    }

    );

    mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button);
    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mQuestionBank.length;
            // mIsCheater=false;
            updateQuestion();

        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(KEY_INDEX, 0);
        mIsCheater[mCurrentIndex] = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(CHEATED);
    }

    mCheatButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cheat_button);
    mCheatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, CheatActivity.class);
            boolean answerIsTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex]
                    .isTrueQuestion();
            i.putExtra(CheatActivity.EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        }
    });
    updateQuestion();

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    savedInstanceState.putInt(KEY_INDEX, mCurrentIndex);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean(CHEATED, mIsCheater[mCurrentIndex]);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d(TAG, "onStop() called");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() called");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.quiz, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}
`

what could be the problem?

please help me..

Comment: Which library are you importing for the actionbar is the support libraryh?

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with bignerdranch.
It seems that because QuizActivity is a subclass of ActionBarActivity
instead of Activity I have to use getSupportActionBar() instead of
getActionBar()